# Is it possible to keep the source code in one location and target many replications in Roku SG?

Tags: brightscript, scenegraph

I have a many applications with different assets like font, image and color etc. but source code are same.

For example: I have 5 or more than 5 different Roku SG application but the all application has same code with different assets like(image, color, font and etc.)
I want to place the code section at specific location and all application access this code from this location.

Is it possible in Roku scene graph?

If yes then please provide me example or URL.

Comment: See also https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=110383

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the different images, colors and other configurable values, then use a config file and host it somewhere on the server.

In your app don't hard code the values and take those configurations from the server based on the application.